# Не работает запрос

Tags: mysqli, php

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT alias FROM env8g_content WHERE alias !== $page_alias")) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO env8g_content (title,alias,introtext,state,sectionid,catid,created,created_by,publish_up) values ($page_title,$page_alias,$page_edit,'1','0','9',$page_date,'982',$page_date)";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
```

Почему не работает, данные правильные.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE alias !== $page_alias
```

замени на

```
WHERE alias != $page_alias
```

а вообще не совсем понятно что вы хотите получить первым запросом?

если совпадение то условие должно быть так

```
if (!($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT alias FROM env8g_content WHERE alias = $page_alias")))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO env8g_content       (title,alias,introtext,state,sectionid,catid,created,created_by,publish_up)  values ($page_title,$page_alias,$page_edit,'1','0','9',$page_date,'982',$page_date)";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
```

а вообще на поле alias поставьте индекс уникальный- и сама MySQL будет проверять на уникальность поле и если что кидать ошибку - вам ее только обработать

кстати возможно вам поможет вставка с указанием директивы  IGNORE или ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, зависит от логики приложения. Посмотрите [тут](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/insert.html)

Comment: первый запрос должен искать совпадения, если не нашел то исполнять функцию